# mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php

I get this error when i configure the database in the shared hosting server

> mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

but it is working properly in the localhost.

```
<?php 
session_start();



if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="localhost")
{
$serverIp="localhost";
$userName="user1";
$password="XXXXX";
$dbname="example";

}else
{


$serverIp="localhost";
$userName="username";
$password="password";
$dbname="dbname";
}

$cn=mysqli_connect($serverIp,$userName,$password) OR Die("Couldn't Connect - ".mysql_error());
$link=mysql_select_db($dbname,$cn)or Die("Couldn't SELCECT - ".mysql_error()); 
?>
```

Comment: `The hostname localhost has a special meaning. It is bound to the use of Unix domain sockets. It is not possible to open a TCP/IP connection using the hostname localhost you must use 127.0.0.1 instead.`-http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php You also are mixing drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are inserting the wrong credentials in the else block, you can try to put the same credentials as the if block and check if that works

Answer (score 8):

Just change your cpanel password and it will work.

Answer (score 6):

In most of the cases, this error can be connected with the recent change of cpanel password or migration of the server to new hosting server..

So this works fine when you connect remotely BUT when you try to access the DB via cpanel at phpmyadmin, you get this

```html
you had the following error with php myadmin: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'wmct4s'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Undefined index: auth_type
```

This will be solved simply by reset the password and restarted cpanel.

the command to restart cpanel is /scripts/restartsrv_cpsrvd

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was you use mysql and mysqli both .
if you want use mysql then you can write:

```
$cn = mysql_connect($serverIp, 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$link = mysql_select_db($dbName,$cn);
```

or if you want use mysqli then you can write:

```
$link= new mysqli($serverIp,$userName,$password,$dbName);
```

Comment: did you check mysqli procedure which i give you last comment?

Answer (score -1):

You don,t need to do anything let alone changing the pass. Change it, and will surely work. Thanks

Comment: "You don't need to ... change the pass." and "Change it and it will work." That seems at conflict with each other, the way I read it. Could you rephrase? Note, I read it as "No need to change anything, not even the password." I could be wrong there, being a non-native...

Answer (score -2):

[I believe this i the php admin mysqli_connect error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV2C2.png)

[I found out this on my cpanel under MySQL Users No db_users.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DQnu.png)

[This the admin panel. WHM in this case also has no db user.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMnsf.png)

restarting my host machine solved the problem. Then #sudo service mysql restart. Before all that resetting the password is compulsory.

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer in text form instead of linking to images

Comment: Ideally add a step by step solution to solve the problem. External Images are not googleable and also not guaranteed to be permanently available.